# Twig template cache with if condition

Tags: php, caching, twig

I have a template that looks like this

```
...
{% if whatever %}
   <div>whatever<div>
{% endif %}
...
```

I setup my environement this way

```
$twig = new \Twig_Environment(
    new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem(
        /template/path/
        ['cache' => '/cache/path/']
    )
);
$whatever = someFunctionFetchingFromDatabase();
$twig->addGlobal('whatever', $whatever);
$twig->render('whatever');
```

Will the compilation cache reset whenever the $whatever variable change ? If it is resetting, what's the point of the compilation cache when variable inside the template changes a lot ?

Thanks for your kind answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that compiled twig becomes php file so all the variable and if are kept into the compiled php file. Using compilation with variable is fine and won't recompile each time the variable change.